# Access fields of node content type from event "rules_entity_insert:comment"

Tags: 8, rules

In Rules 8, I know how to make custom fields of a content type accessible in an event "After updating a content item (rules_entity_update:node)", that is:

```
Condition: Entity is of bundle
Entity: node
Type: node
Bundle: my_content_type
```

So that I can use something like {{node.my_custom_field.value}}.

But, when I'm in an event "After saving a new comment (rules_entity_insert:comment)", the above solution does not work. How should I do to access custom fields of the node the comment is attached to?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find an answer using Rules, and ended up adding some code:

```
function my-module_comment_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
{
   // Get NID and load Node
   $nid = $entity->get('entity_id')->target_id;
   $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
}
```

From there I can use $node->get('field_something'). Of course if it's an entity reference field (as per my case), there's some work to do.